# Monitor data change in redshift

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, triggers, amazon-redshift, monitor

I am trying to find a tool, or methodology to store when an update is done against an specific table and column in AWS Redshift.

In PostgreSQL there is a way of doing this with triggers, but Redshift does not support these triggers.

Can we monitor updates statements and store the timestamp, the old value, the new one, and the table affected?

Comment: yes of course - you would have to do this yourself (build your own process) - your update process needs to store the change somehow. maybe you could get better help if you explain why you are trying to do this, for what reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no in-built capability** in Amazon Redshift to do change detection.

Amazon Redshift is intended as a **Data Warehouse**, which typically means that bulk information is loaded from external sources. It should be relatively rare for data to be updated *within* Amazon Redshift because it is not intended to be used as an [OLTP database](https://searchdatacenter.techtarget.com/definition/OLTP).

Thus, it would be better to put change detection in the **source database** or in the ETL pipeline, rather than Redshift.